# Unable to add Git repository hosted on OS X Server

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos, git

I created a repository on OS X Server called *myTestRepo*. For HTTPS Access, I am allowing logged in users to read and write.

When I try to add this repository in Xcode, I get an error. 
In repository address, if I enter

```
ssh://iMac/git/myTestRepo.git
```

I get the following error

```
Could not read from remote repository.
```

If I enter

```
https://iMac/git/myTestRepo.git
```

I get the  following error

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://iMac/git/myTestRepo.git/': Could not resolve host:iMac
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I also tried replacing iMac with the server name. Same result.

Comment: Specify username (probably `git`), also give full path to repo including git user home path (probably `/Users/git`): `ssh://git@iMac/Users/git/myTestRepo.git`

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work.

Comment: Try to clone the repo from terminal command line: `git clone ssh://git@iMac/Users/git/myTestRepo.git`. This should give more verbose error messages (please copy and paste them here). Also try with `iMac` replaced by ip number.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a DNS problem in your local network:

Try substituting "iMac" with the IP adress of the computer hosting the repo:

```
ifconfig |grep inet
```

(in Terminal) will print out your local IP (e.g. 192.168.18.15).

If this doesn't help try pinging the IP / Computername (iMac) to see if you are able to connect to the computer:

```
ping iMac
ping 192.168.18.15
```

I also found a good tutorial on how to setup git Mac OSX Server. http://www.tomdalling.com/blog/software-processes/how-to-set-up-a-secure-git-server-at-home-osx/

Pay attention to the port forwarding section, did you forward ports correctly?